# Using cpplint on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit, c

I want to use cpplint for C style checking. How do I do it on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  32-bit machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Install cpplint

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip  
pip install --user cpplint
```

#### Usage

cpplint is an automated checker to make sure a C++ file follows Google's C++ style guide. Following Google's C++ style guide helps to prettify your C++ code and makes it easier to read.

Run cpplint with:

```
cpplint [OPTIONS] files
```

For full usage instructions, run:

```
cpplint --help
```

---

Alternatively, you can download ccplint.py from [GitHub cpplint: static code checker for C++](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint) webpage and run cpplint without installing it as follows:

```
python cpplint.py file.cpp
```